# Trigger Controller Function Based on DropDownList

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having problem to trigger a function according selected dropdown list

here's the script on the same page as table:

```
var total = $("#total").val();
var b = 1;

while (b <= total) {
    $('#opt'+b).change(function() {
        var opt = $('#opt'+b).val();
        if (opt == "I") {
            id = $("#idx"+b).val();
            qty = $("#qtx"+b).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('item/insert_rent'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: "id="+id+"&qty="+qty,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {}
            })
        } else {
            //Delete Function
        }
    }
}


<table>
    <thead>
        <th><b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>QTY</b></th>
        <th><b>Action</b></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $x = 1;
            foreach ($detail as $d):
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $d->id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $d->qty?></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="opt<?php echo $x; ?>" id="opt<?php echo $x; ?>">
                      <option value="D" selected>Delete</option>
                      <option value="I">Insert</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" id="idx<?php echo $x; ?>" name="idx<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $d->id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="qtyx<?php echo $x; ?>" name="qtyx<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $d->qty; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $x++;
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="<?php echo $x - 1; ?>">
```

The result on table are several rows, each row contains 1 dropdown list
and each dropdown list change will trigger function in controller.

And this my insert function:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$qty = $this->input->post('qt');
$data = [
    'id' => $id,
    'qty' => $qty
];
$this->my_model->insertData('temporary', $data);
```

Where did i go wrong? and is there better way than this? (i'm sure there is, my logic is messed up)

Comment: why it's `$this->input->post('opt'.$a=="I")` ? `$a=="I"` ??

Comment: edited, it was the function before i made changes using script

Comment: This question is really unclear. Are your asking how to trigger a PHP codeigniter function when a select dropdown menu option is changed? Or are you asking how you trigger a PHP native function when a select dropdown menu option is changed? Is your PHP function in the same file or in a controller class?